# Why is this ripple effect is not working as expected?

Tags: android, drawable, material-design

I am using a drawable to change the background and text of textViews inside of my navigation drawer. I would like to keep the background white for the text area, but by testing keeping the background white does not show the ripple effect on the background, instead it does it to the text making the text gray. In the picture below, the middle one is being pressed causing the ripple effect.

[image: The ripple effect]

Here are my drawable files that are used to make the changes in colors

Background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/selected" android:state_activated="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/white" />
</selector>
```

Text:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/primary" android:state_activated="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/primary_text" />
</selector>
```

textView layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25.0sp"
        android:background="@drawable/activated_background"
        android:textColor="@drawable/activated_text"
        android:id="@id/text1"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dip" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: refer my answer below

Answer (score 2):

you should use 2 drawable files and use it as your view background.
for pre-lolipop versions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/white_list_item_selected_background" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />

</selector>
```

for lolipop (v21):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/white_list_item_selected_background" >
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />

</ripple>
```

Comment: i know about creating another one for pre-lollipop support, I am focusing on the post-lollipop design issues first. Attempting to use the lollipop one it fails at the point that the selected one does not have a change in color. Every attempt I did to change the color of selected one failed.

Comment: Here is an image showing how this is is somewhat of a solution: http://puu.sh/kh5T1/7561478f88.png first, the selected one in blue text does not have selected background, the middle one is being clicked on in the picture and the selected background does not fill the padding space up to the other items.

Answer (score 0):

If you use custom background, ripple effect will not be shown. You may have to use other ripple library such as [Material Ripple](https://github.com/balysv/material-ripple).

Comment: The ripple effect looks perfect on the one with a gray background though. The ones that I want to blend in with the background (white) do not look fine.

Comment: I added it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

In my case ripple effect is working after the first click, but for first click it didn't work for me. Have changed the background selector file with **android:state_activated="true"** and in main.xml **android:clickable="true"** then it's work fine for all time.

selector.xml (under res\drawable\selector.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/card_bg_pressed" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/card_bg_focused" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/card_bg_selected" android:state_enabled="false" android:state_selected="true"/>
</selector>
```

In activity_main.xml

```
 <com.mysample.RecyclingImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview_overlay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/selector"
    android:clickable="true" />
```